# Removing multiple characters from a string in c# using MyString.Remove(x,y)

Tags: c#, .net, string, teltonika

While running a program in my server (a *beacon* *detection* code), I will receive a variable size string, named **io385**.

The string length can vary according to how many *beacons* are detected:

- One beacon: 46 bytes (first 4 bytes are useless, next 40 are **important**, next 2 are useless);
- Two beacons: 90 bytes (first 2 bytes are useless, next 40 are **important**, next 2 are useless);
- Three beacons: 134 bytes (first 2 bytes are useless, next 40 are **important**, next 2 are useless;

...

So, with this, my idea is to remove whatever is useless. Even though the string can vary in size, I always want to remove bytes on fixed positions (for the first beacon, *first* four and *last* 2; for the next beacons, *first* two and *last* two).

I started to manually remove the useless bytes on a 2 *beacon* string. However, I wanted to optimize this in order to automatically work whether the string is 46 bytes or xxxx bytes (otherwise, I'll have to manually code the character removal process for each possible string length).

```
        string io385 = "11210000AAAA0000AAAA0000AAAA0000AAAA0A0A0A0ABF210000BBBB0000BBBB0000BBBB0000BBBB0B0B0B0BBF";
        string informacao = String.Copy(io385);
        
        informacao = informacao.Remove(0,4).Remove(40,2).Remove(40,2).Remove(80,2);
        
        
        int x = io385.Length;
        int y = informacao.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", io385); 
        Console.WriteLine("Copied String: {0}", informacao);
        Console.WriteLine("Original String length: {0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("Copied String length: {0}", y);
```

Comment: You say you want to remove "bytes", but are you really referring to characters? Different character sets have a different numbers of bytes per character.

Comment: Does this question actually have anything to do with `teltonika`? It sounds like it's only about removing characters from a string.

Comment: Iterator method, if(length = 46) substring else for loop  i+=44  substring yield

Comment: @RufusL My bad, yes I mean characters, not bytes. Also, yes, all equipments are manufactured by teltonika, added the tag since it could be useful to other people!

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm new to C# (only coded in C / C++) but I understand your idea! I'll try to create a solution based around that and edit the post as soon as I'm done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetStuff(string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Length);
    if (input.Length == 46)
        yield return input.Substring(4, 40);
    else
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 44)
            yield return input.Substring(i + 2, 40);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "xxxx1234567890123456789012345678901234567890xx";
var input2 = "xx1234567890123456789012345678901234567890xxxx1234567890123456789012345678901234567890xxxx1234567890123456789012345678901234567890xxxx1234567890123456789012345678901234567890xx";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", GetStuff(input)));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", GetStuff(input2)));
```

**Output**

```
46
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890

176
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2w7l6v)

Comment: @PoulBak iterators are nice and succinct

Comment: Awesome! I suppose this is exactly what @MichaelRandall was talking about! Like I said earlier, I'm new to C# but I understand the main idea benhind the code!

Comment: @Jonaas18 I am Michael Randall :)

Comment: Oh sorry ahah :P I'm currently creating the code from scratch and commenting while going through each line in order to understand it properly! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to first remove the first two characters so that all the "beacons" are the same length (44 characters) in the string. Now we can create a loop in which we go from `0` to `length / 44`, where we skip `iteration * 44` characters (i.e. skip previous beacons), then skip `2` more characters (i.e. the leading 2 for this beacon) and then take `40` characters (the number of characters we care about).

In a method this might look something like this:

```
public static string RemoveUselessCharacters(string input)
{
    // Add argument validation first
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || input.Length < 46) return input;

    // Just remove the first two characters right away
    input = input.Substring(2);

    // This will hold the result
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop once for every beacon
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length / 44; i++)
    {
         // Skip previous beacons plus two characters, then take 40 characters
        result.Append(string.Concat(input.Skip(i * 44 + 2).Take(40)));
    }

    // Return just the beacon charcters for all the beacons
    return result.ToString();
}
```

If you wanted to modify the code to return a `List<string>`, where each string was a separate beacon, it is easily done:

```
public static List<string> GetBeacons(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || input.Length < 46) 
        return new List<string> {input};

    input = input.Substring(2);
    var result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length / 44; i++)
    {
        result.Add(string.Concat(input.Skip(i * 44 + 2).Take(40)));
    }

    return result;
}
```